# Python Pandas - Dataframe total by year appearing in one row

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following code that summarizes data into the table below listed under Output

```
df['Customer ID'] = df['Ship To Customer'] + df['ZipCleaned']

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

min_dates = df.groupby(['Customer ID'])['Date'].min()
df['First_Purchase_Date'] = df.apply(lambda row: min_dates.loc[row['Customer ID']], axis=1) 
df['New Customer'] = df['Date'] <= df['First_Purchase_Date']
df['Existing Customer'] = df['Date'] > df['First_Purchase_Date']
df['Total Customers'] = (df['New Customer']==True).value_counts() + (df['Existing Customer']==True).value_counts() 

df['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['revenue']) 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='s')
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['First_Purchase_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['First_Purchase_Date'], unit='s')

FPRANGE = df.First_Purchase_Date.between('2014-01-01','2019-12-03') #customer first purchase dates we want to include in the dataset

Table = df.loc[FPRANGE].groupby(df['Year'])[['New Customer', 'Existing Customer', 'Total Customers','revenue']].sum() #with date filter on first purchase date

print(Table)
```

OUTPUT

```
      New Customer  Existing Customer  Total Customers   revenue
Year
2014          7.00               2.00           156.00 11,869.47
2015          1.00               3.00             0.00  9,853.93
2016          5.00               3.00             0.00  4,058.53
2017          9.00               3.00             0.00  8,056.37
2018         12.00               7.00             0.00 22,031.23
2019         16.00              10.00             0.00 97,142.42
```

Notice that the total customers column has an amount under 2014 and not the rest of the rows by year.  I want to be able to see the total number of customers for each year (ie New Customer + Existing Customer).  I have tried several different approaches but can't seem to get this right.

Comment: You mean `Table['Total Customers'] = Table['New Customer'] + Table['Existing Customer']`?

Comment: yes. when I add Table['Total Customers'] = Table['New Customer'] + Table['Existing Customer'] into my code it gives me the same result

Comment: So if I get it right, you are doing `Table['Total Customers'] = Table['New Customer'] + Table['Existing Customer']` after the groupby. Because then its straightforward column to column addition and I don't see any reason why that would produce the result you said its giving

Comment: Actually that seems to be working now. Not sure why it was causing an issue before.   Do you think I need this line?  When I comment it out the code produces the same output.  I initially put it in as the code was double counting the number of customers. 

'df['Total Customers'] = (df['New Customer']==True).value_counts() + (df['Existing Customer']==True).value_counts()'

Comment: You should really stick to a single column indexing scheme, ideally the `df[]` one.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested solution above worked

```
Table['Total Customers'] = Table['New Customer'] + Table['Existing Customer']
```